# Rerender line count React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to create something like a text editor online, based in React. I would like to add near the textarea a div that counts the line that I am currently using. So, I created a funciotn that counts the lines in the textarea, then added an element that gets that number and create that list. The problem is that when I render, it creates the list corectly, but when I write something, it doesn't rerender. The problem it that when I write something, it doesn't rerender. Here is my code:

```
const Editor = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('//');

    const handleChanges = (e) => {
        setText(e.target.value);   
    }

    const countLine = () => {
        let lines = text.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
        let count = lines.length;
        return  count;
    }

    return <>
        <form className="editor">
            <div>
                <li>{/*this is where i create the numbers*/}
                {<ul>{Array.from(Array(countLine), (e, i) => {
                    return <li key={i}>{i}</li>
                    })}</ul>}
                </li>
            </div>
            <textarea name="text" value={text} className="editorText" onChange={handleChanges} spellCheck="false" 
            id = {bg}></textarea>
        </form>
    </>
}
```

I would like that when I make the change, the code makes automatically the update to the number of line, but I can't work with the handleChanges funtion, or at least, I didn't find how. Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved adding a new state value, that every times that there is a change, is recalculated. Then , the numbers are recreated. Here is the code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Editor = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('//Your code');
    const [line, setLine] = useState(1);


    const handleChanges = (e) => {
        setText(e.target.value); 
        setLine(countLine); 
    }

    const countLine = () => {
        let lines = text.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
        let count = lines.length;
        console.log(count);
        return  count;
    }

    return <>
        <form className="editor">
            <div>
                <div class="number"> 
                    <ul>
                        {Array.from(Array(line), (e, i) => {
                            return <li key={i}>{i + 1}</li>
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <textarea name="code" value={text} className="editorText" onChange={handleChanges} spellCheck="false" 
            id = {bg}></textarea>
        </form>
    </>
}

export default Editor;
```